# you have confused me or you have got me confused?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

You have confused me by staying quiet about it or you have got me confused by staying quiet about it?

I know the latter is correct, but is the former sentence correct as well and convey the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

Your preferred (second) sentence uses the word *confused* to refer to an attribute or characteristic of a person **I am confused**.

The same word can be used to describe (in the past tense) the action of another person to produce that attribute **You confused me**.

So the two statements do convey the same meaning.

Life becomes a little more complicated when the state of befuddlement arises not from the actions of an external agent but from one's own.

**Because I removed he flange before I disconnected the lubricator, I confused myself when it came time to adjust the reciprocator** is a more honest expression than **The instructions were very confusing**.

Answer (score 0):

> You have/got me confused

Mean's "you" is the one who is confused.  "me" is what "you" is confused about.
  As in:  *You have me confused with someone else.*

> You have/got confused me

Means "me" is the one who is confused. "you" is who is to blame for "me" being confused.

Have and got are interchangeable here.  They only impact tense.  What matters is the order of the words "me" and "confused".

Answer (score 0):

***You have confused me*** means you confused me.

***You have got me confused*** means you made some situation due to which I got confused.

Both mean the same but mostly You have got me confused is mostly used in US English.

Comment: I am waiting for a grammarian to check this answer and other answers  because the original post confuses me, and I think there is something wrong with other questions too.